# how i can reset identity column sql server all tables after delete values?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database and clear all data by command. I want to reset identity key of all tables.

Comment: Like [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/15/sql-server-dbcc-reseed-table-identity-value-reset-table-identity/)?

Comment: yes, thanks.  but i want have function to reset all database tables identity key

Comment: Why don't you drop and recreate the tables?

Comment: Because This Is a  restored database with many stored procedures and function's and I don't  want do that.

Comment: Dropping and recreating the tables has no effect on the stored procedures and functions (other than they won't work in the short period of time that you're dropping and recreating the tables).

Comment: Why don't you truncate the tables when clearing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using an undocumented stored procedure, you can use `sp_MSforeachtable`:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'DBCC CHECKIDENT ([?], reseed, 1)'
```

Comment: reseed ,0 or 1? for tarting from 1 it must not be 0?